# intel server motherboard S5520HC not booting

Tags: intel, hardware

This server was working fine when we took it out the rack, now it seems lifeless.

I have tried all the normal checks, booted off one cpu, changed memory.

When you put power to the board, it turns on it self. It will not turn off with the switch. The CPU fan will be on full speed and it does 3 long beeps. However on the 3rd beep it cuts short.

On the sys_sts LEDS, it is orange

I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Try reset BIOS (Battery out or change jumper position). Try start without RAM and see the beeps the same.

Comment: I have tried different memory slots. Have also tried to reset the bios. Done all the basic things. I don't want to admit its dead, since it is a £5,000 server! Only conclusion I can come to is the mobo has had it.

Comment: This will not help you but we've had exactly the same problem. The board was dead, and happened two times.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manual for that model of motherboard, three beeps indicate a memory error.  So, you've probably had a DIMM go bad or work itself loose.  Track down the bad DIMM(s) by seeing which ones prevent the system from booting and replace it/them.

http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/s5520hc/sb/e39529013_s5520hc_s5500hcv_s5520hct_tps_r1_9.pdf

(Page 169, Table 87)

Answer (score 0):

- Check if the RAM and CPU/Cooler are seated correctly
- Put in the old RAM and see if it's working again.

Comment: tried old memory, made sure the cpu and cooler are seated..

what ever I do, as soon as I put power in. It turns itself on and max's out the cpu fan(s)

Answer (score 0):

Try running it out of the rack again. If changing components doesn't work, it is possible that there was a short circuit and that it caused catastrophic damage to the motherboard.

Do a visual inspection of the entire board from both sides. Any discolouration might indicate a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue...
Found a rogue mount point under the board (not under a hole of motherboard) which over time had scratched trough the PCB`s lacque and made a short circuit.